# Is this a good way to keep track of daily views?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I have a views table that keeps track of daily views. We use this table to show daily and monthly line charts. The table looks like:

```
id, post_id, day, month, year, count.
```

Which means for every post, there is 365 views (in a year). This means if I have 1,000 posts. I would have 365,000 entries in the views table. We have several posts and counting. Sometimes 10 posts a day.

I've put an index on `post_id`, `day`, `month` and `year`.

Am worried that this may lead to db performance issues as the table grows exponentially? Should I be concerned? Or should I be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making things more difficult for yourself than you need to.  Why don't you just have a table defined like this:

```
create table daily_views
( post_id int not null
, view_date date not null
, count int not null
, primary key (post_id, view_date)
, foreign key (post_id) references post(post_id)
)
```

Unless you have a child table that references the `daily_views` table there is no particular advantage to having an auto-increment ID on `daily_views`.  In fact, you'd just be wasting space for an index that is less useful than the natural key, which is `post_id` and `view_date`.

There is no advantage to splitting day, month and year into separate columns.  If you store the date as a single field it is more efficient and you can easily aggregate across any date range, not just on days of the month, months and years.

By using this table format you will optimize the space used and the access to records which will mitigate any concern you have about performace and scalability.  In terms of the number of rows you are generating, I don't think you need to worry about that.  Lots and lots of databases have tables with many millions of rows.  You just want to make sure each row is as compact as possible.

Comment: I think you mean view_date... not post_date.

Comment: "There is no advantage to splitting day, month and year into separate columns." -- So true, write the query to sum the views from 11/20/2011 to 12/10/2011... such a pain.

Comment: Quite right @StephaniePage.  I've corrected my answer accordingly.  Thanks!